# Definition of wilson's theorem

Tags: modular-arithmetic

The statement of wilson's theorem states that, for any prime number n>1

$( n-1 )! \equiv -1 \mod n$

Is this equivalent to saying that

$( n-1 )! \equiv n-1\mod n$

If no, what is the difference ?,
If yes, why are we doing the same thing in $2$ different ways?

Thanks

Comment: Yes they are equivalent.  There are infinitely many integers $m\equiv -1\pmod n$ so there are infinitely many ways to write the same congruence.

Comment: Yes they are equivalent, because $-1 = n-1$ (mod $n$). Your second question does not make sense: it happens all the time for two sentences expressed with different words/symbols/numerals to be logically equivalent.

Comment: As everyone above said, they are equivalent. But I feel that if you are not comfortable with the fact that $-1 \equiv n-1 (modn)$ and the reason behind this, then you are probably not ready to understand Wilson's Theorem yet. I would advise you to really internalize the basic properties of modular arithmetic before moving on to more advanced statements.

Comment: Ok I'll do that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These two formulations are the same because $n-1 \equiv -1 \pmod{n}$. That is independent of Wilson's theorem.

Which formulation you prefer is a matter of taste. The one with $n-1$ is the least positive remainder.

Comment: Ok I get that, It means -1 mod n and n-1 mod n are equivalent and can be used in place of each other .

Comment: As are any numbers seperated by a multiple of n ...